# What if l run "sudo apt uninstall sudo"?

Tags: sudo

I did not run this command in terminal,but what will happen if i did?i'm just curious.And if something bad happens,how can we solve this?

Comment: When you start to ask yourself these questions, a good set up backups is wise. So is a fresh LiveInstall USB.

Comment: You would get an error message because `apt` does not know about `uninstall`.